# How to initialize argv array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize *argv with these values : test_file model result
Can anyone help me how to directly initialize the argv instead of using command line. I am doing it like this:

```
*argv[]= {"test_file","model","output",NULL};
```

but its not working. I know its simple but i am new to programming. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am doing this because i don't want to pass these arguments at run time fro terminal but directly inside program

Comment: Can you show who is accepting these arguments and how you're calling it ? Are you trying to pass some "default" arguments to main ?

Comment: You can have a look at the code sum-predict.c here:http://code.metager.de/source/xref/libsvm/svm-predict.c  These arguments are used for opening the test file model file and save an output

Comment: @cnicutar: I sometimes use this kind of thing when developing in an IDE because I find having to change the IDE project settings for command line arguments to be more painful than modifying a line of code in the editor when I'm debugging and need to try out different command lines.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, that makes perfect sense :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
char* dummy_args[] = { "dummyname", "arg1", "arg2 with spaces", "arg3", NULL };

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    argv = dummy_args;
    argc = sizeof(dummy_args)/sizeof(dummy_args[0]) - 1;

    // etc...

    return 0;
}
```

One thing to be aware of is that the standard `argv` strings are permitted to be modified. These replacement ones cannot be (they're literals).  If you need that capability (which many option parsers might), you'll need something a bit smarter.  Maybe something like:

```
int new_argv( char*** pargv, char** new_args) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int new_argc = 0;
    char** tmp = new_args;

    while (*tmp) {
        ++new_argc;
        ++tmp;
    }

    tmp = malloc( sizeof(char*) * (new_argc + 1));
    // if (!tmp) error_fail();

    for (i = 0; i < new_argc; ++i) {
        tmp[i] = strdup(new_args[i]);
    }
    tmp[i] = NULL;

    *pargv = tmp;

    return new_argc;
}
```

That gets called like so:

```
argc = new_argv( &argv, dummy_args);
```

Comment: Bu doing as you suggested i am receiving this error:warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Comment: @wishee77 - Yep, that's because (as Michael wrote), the standard `argv` strings are pointers to `char*`, which can be modified.  The `char* dummy_args[] = {};` produces an array of pointers to string constants, that is, `const char *`.  You'll need to use `strdup` and `malloc` to create an array of mutable `char*` strings, but that seems over-the-top for this.

Comment: More to the point, you're not modifying these strings (just reading them and printing them to stderr), so you can ignore this error if this is a one-time thing.

Answer (score 1):

or simply put, does this work (sorry its 3 years late ;) ) ?

```
int argc ;
char * argv[3] ;

char  p1[16]  ;
char  p2[16]  ;
char  p3[16]  ;

memcpy ( p1, "mainwindow", 9 ) ;
memcpy ( p2, "–SizeHint5", 10 ) ;
memcpy ( p3, "120x240", 7 )  ;

argc = 3 ;
argv[0] = p1 ;
argv[1] = p2 ;
argv[2] = p3 ;

QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

Comment: At the very least, you forgot that argv should have a NULL entry at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Initialisation like that is only available at declaration time, and (presumably) you've declared argv as a parameter to your function (`main` I assume).
You will have to assign each individually in this instance.

Comment: Yes you are right i have already declared argv. Can you explain how to assign them individually.

Comment: It's really hard to see what you actually intend to do with it without more code. I think explaining string assignments might directly answer your question but not be what you need to do, if that makes sense.

Comment: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/libsvm/svm-predict.c I am using it for the main() function. The code is long that's why i am posting this link. The main function reads these files using argv. It works fine from terminal but i want to include it directly in the code.

Comment: Then rather than assign things directly to argv, use @michael 's fix

Comment: I did the way he said but now i am getting this new error:warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'. How to solve this now?

Answer (score 0):

To conform with newer compilers, I would do this (as long as you don't want to change the strings):

```
char* argv[] = {const_cast<char*> ("program_name"),
                const_cast<char*> ("-arg1"),
                const_cast<char*> ("string_to_arg1"),
                const_cast<char*> ("-arg2"),
                const_cast<char*>("-arg3"),
                NULL};
int argc = sizeof (argv) / sizeof (char*) - 1;

QApplication app(argc, argv);
```