# how to change the arguments of main function before running it

Tags: c, compiler-construction, program-entry-point

In the following code, I want to change the arguments of main function without modifying main function.

Recently, I read the code of AFL fuzzing tool, for the forkserver, I do not understand how to pass the parameters to the target program, so I write this simple program.

I have tried to use pipe to redirect stdin and write parameters to stdin, but it does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

__attribute__((constructor))
void __start() {
    static unsigned char tmp[4];
    int count = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    while(count < 3){
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) _exit(1);
        if(!pid){
            //how to pass "hello" to main without modfiying main function.
            return;
        }

        count++;
        if(count == 3) _exit(1);
    }
    //_exit(0);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    printf("%d %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If "hello" in argv, argc should be 2 and the output should have "1 hello".

Comment: Simple solution:call `execvp` (or some other `exec*`) after you fork. You don't need to redirect stdin to stdin after the fork, but you might want to redirect it to *something else* because having multiple forked children with the same stdin doesn't work and multiple forked children sharing the same `stdout` and/or `stderr` tends to result in unreadable interleaved output.

Comment: The system call exexvp (or other exec*) is used to execute a program. In my program, the __start function is running before main, so when we want to run the actual program--main() many times, we do not need to load and initialize it many times like the forkserver of afl-fuzz.

Comment: These might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3848603/12711 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/12076848/12711

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelBurr These two links are useful. Although we can parse the argv without argc, some real program also need argc to parse argv. If I want to instrument start function into a binary file, but it need argc like the above main function, so how the argc and argv of main can be changed in start dynamically?

Comment: From the fact that you are prepared to add `__start` to your binary, I'm assuming that when you say "without modifying main", you nonetheless are prepared to modify the binary. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Modifying the C Runtime Environment's `int argc` argument counter *before* the C `int main(int argc, char **argv)` method is called. . . - - - = = = (; A NASTY HACK ;) = = = - - - . . .

---

**I am using:**

- The latest C++ compiler currently available for OS X High Sierra,
- Installed the currently standard way, using `brew`.

**To reproduce the results below `argc.cpp` code listing**, either:

- Update your Mac OS setup to reflect mine,
- [Install GNU compilers on your Ubuntu 64](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers)
- Install GNU compilers for your particular setup

---

**argc.cpp :**

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    __attribute__((constructor)) void start(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int * pc = (int *) argv - 2; // NASTY HACK TO GET C RUNTIME argc * ;)
        printf("argc = %d \n", *pc); // the original argc, on most systems ;)
        int NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS_NEEDED_FOR_FUZZING = 1; // Replace this line 
        // with the simple/complex logic needed for fuzz testing (fuzzing)
        if(!(argc > NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS_NEEDED_FOR_FUZZING)){ 
            argc = NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS_NEEDED_FOR_FUZZING + 1;
            *pc = argc; // NASTY HACK TO OVERWRITE C RUNTIME argc ;)
        } 
        // *pc = 2; // uncomment this to see that you can also reduce argc
        argv[1] = "hello"; // Example setting of a fuzzy argument
        // Add more lines, a loop, etc... here to set more fuzzy arguments 
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%s: argv[%d] = '%s'\n", __FUNCTION__, i, argv[i]);
        }
        printf("argc = %d \n", argc); // the possibly modified argc
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%s: argv[%d] = '%s'\n", __FUNCTION__, i, argv[i]);
        }
        printf("argc = %d \n", argc); // the possibly modified argc
        return 0;
    }
```

---

### Mac OS Terminal:

---

**Compilation:**

```
    $ /usr/local/bin/c++-9 argc.cpp -o argc
```

---

**Running** with `0` arguments, original `int argc = 1`:

```
    $ ./argc
    argc = 1 
    start: argv[0] = './argc'
    start: argv[1] = 'hello'
    argc = 2 
    main: argv[0] = './argc'
    main: argv[1] = 'hello'
    argc = 2
```

---

**Running** with `3` arguments, original `int argc = 4`:

```
    $ ./argc 1 2 3
    argc = 4 
    start: argv[0] = './argc'
    start: argv[1] = 'hello'
    start: argv[2] = '2'
    start: argv[3] = '3'
    argc = 4 
    main: argv[0] = './argc'
    main: argv[1] = 'hello'
    main: argv[2] = '2'
    main: argv[3] = '3'
    argc = 4
```

---

**Running** , to demonstrate `argc` reduction capability,

- **after uncommenting line 13 and recompiling** (that hardcodes `argc = 2`) :

```
        *pc = 2; // uncomment this to see that you can also reduce argc
```

with the same `3` arguments, as above, original `int argc = 4`:

```
    $ ./argc 1 2 3
    argc = 4 
    start: argv[0] = './argc'
    start: argv[1] = 'hello'
    start: argv[2] = '2'
    start: argv[3] = '3'
    argc = 4 
    main: argv[0] = './argc'
    main: argv[1] = 'hello'
    argc = 2
```

---

If the **C Runtime Environment** is **not** initialized on your system similar to the listing:

- [Initialization code run first thing by the ELF startup code of the GNU C Library](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/init-first.c;h=10762b61f590df5e2bde19d6554e21e8cacc76ee;hb=HEAD),

you may need to either:

- Research the difference, by comparing your local **C Runtime Environment** to the GNU sample above, and/or
- Experimentally modify my code, until it works for you. For example: walk the int pointers ***before*** and also ***!after!*** the location of `argv` and see what you find there...

If you find hacking your current **C Runtime Environment** too hard, try to:

- [Install GNU compilers on your Ubuntu 64](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers),
- Install GNU compilers for your particular setup.

---

### Here is how/why this hack works:

1. The `C Runtime Environment` function applicable for your setup (there are multiple possibilities) saves the `int argc, char **argv, char **envp` arguments in some memory locations - these are luckily adjacent in case of my setup.
2. On my `64 bit` system, due to memory alignment rules the `int argc` address would be just 1 extra `sizeof(int)` ahead of the memory pointed to by `char **argv`, that is why the `- 2` in the: `int * pc = (int *) argv - 2;` line is not `- 1`.

---

```
╦ ╦  ╔═╗  ╔═╗  ╔═╗  ╦ ╦       ╦ ╦  ╔═╗  ╔═╗  ╦╔═  ╦  ╔╗╔  ╔═╗ ╦ ╦ ╦
╠═╣  ╠═╣  ╠═╝  ╠═╝  ╚╦╝  ───  ╠═╣  ╠═╣  ║    ╠╩╗  ║  ║║║  ║ ╦ ║ ║ ║
╩ ╩  ╩ ╩  ╩    ╩     ╩        ╩ ╩  ╩ ╩  ╚═╝  ╩ ╩  ╩  ╝╚╝  ╚═╝ o o o
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't understand why 'argc' is not shared between start and main. If we cannot modify main function, the output does not exit "1 hello". In some scenarios, such as instrument of a binary file, we cannot modify the binary file to change its 'argc'.

Comment: 'argc' is not a pointer, so we change it in start function, which cannot affect the actual value of 'argc' of main function. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful. However, I cannot reproduce it on my computer with x86_64 ubuntu system. I have tried the address from (int *) argv - 1 to (int *) argv - 12, the value of argc was not changed, but it is a good starting point for me to hack it.

Comment: Great, my pleasure, please try to also explore the int pointers after the argv, (+2, +4 etc...) If you find hacking your current C Runtime Environment too hard, try to install GNU compilers on your Ubuntu 64: [help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers].